# How to make div overflow instead of going on new line?

Tags: css

Want to create a slider containing 3 image containers and need all of them in the same row. All image containers are same size, but the size of slider is around 2.5 images, so the third one should overflow instead of going to new row. Example:

How it should look

[image: How it should look]

What i have for now

[image: What I have for now]

html

```
    <div class="image-slide-wrapper">
      <div class="images-section">
        <div class="image-slide">
          <div class="slide-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-slide">
          <div class="slide-img">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-slide">
         <div class="slide-img">
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

scss

```
.image-slide-wrapper {
        float: left;
        height: 55%;
        width: 100%;
        .images-section {
          float: left;
          height: 85%;
          width: 100%;
          border: 1px solid grey;
          border-radius: 8px;
          overflow: hidden;
          padding: 0.125rem;
        }
        .image-slide {
          float: left;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100px;
          margin-right: 0.25rem;
          .slide-img {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 0.35rem;
            background-color: #e9e9e9;
```

in the text slider is images-section class and image container is image-slide class. Forgot to mention that I have to go with float to make consistent with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 250px;">
  <div style="width: max-content">
    <img style="width: 100px;height: 100px;border: 1px solid black;" src="...">
    <img style="width: 100px;height: 100px;border: 1px solid black;" src="...">
    <img style="width: 100px;height: 100px;border: 1px solid black;" src="...">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate it, max-content value for width is what i was missing.

Answer (score 0):

This works. You can add `display:flex;` and `flex-wrap:nowrap;` to `.image-slide-wrapper` class.

```css
    .main {
        float: left;
        height: 85%;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 8px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0.125rem;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap:nowrap;
    }
    
    .slider {
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        width: 300px;
        margin-right: 0.25rem;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="slider">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBYCs940TLL3tx_nyn7fVeidXWZyfOKV5QrQ&usqp=CAU">
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBYCs940TLL3tx_nyn7fVeidXWZyfOKV5QrQ&usqp=CAU">
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <img class="img" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTBYCs940TLL3tx_nyn7fVeidXWZyfOKV5QrQ&usqp=CAU">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove `float` from the thumb elements and use `display: flex` and `flex-flow: row nowrap` on the container

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.125rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.image-slide {
  height: calc(100% - .25rem);
  flex: 1 0 100px;
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="image-slide"></div>
   <div class="image-slide"></div>
   <div class="image-slide"></div>
   <div class="image-slide"></div>  
</div>
```